# Flutter PWA service worker fails to successfully register

Tags: flutter, iis, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've built my flutter app and have the pwa version of it, hosted it on windows server `IIS 10` with a valid ssl certificate on subdomain like `Https://pwa.mydomain.com`, but when I visit the page, it doesn't show the `Install app` button on chrome. How can I solve this?

What I've done so far:
Removed the references to files that did not exist anymore in the project.

Here is my service worker:

```
'use strict';
const MANIFEST = 'flutter-app-manifest';
const TEMP = 'flutter-temp-cache';
const CACHE_NAME = 'flutter-app-cache';
const RESOURCES = {
  ".dart_tool/package_config.json": "23791ac6df06edd3cb7ca99ab6949a5a",
".dart_tool/package_config_subset": "8453ab6a2adbaeda61d2d58965841223",
".dart_tool/version": "a13ed25c1389038783693bec771e71f6",
"assets/assets/images/svgIcon/wifiOff.svg": "ca97536b42e250214b667a606455a58f",
"assets/FontManifest.json": "fba83cca6cbe4083e6cc0498e15a1a6f",
"assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf": "4e6447691c9509f7acdbf8a931a85ca1",
"assets/NOTICES": "0e94f133a57e1e05b650363a497d95b0",
"assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf": "6d342eb68f170c97609e9da345464e5e",
"favicon.png": "19e188c1100dbd706d3d81309d478996",
"icons/launcher_logo192.png": "ea22e4258d33a9a184a426b38f3e6f46",
"icons/launcher_logo512.png": "19e188c1100dbd706d3d81309d478996",
"index.html": "fde3d71f9f8a4623bd98e956040169d2",
"/": "fde3d71f9f8a4623bd98e956040169d2",
"lib/main.dart": "5515740aeb62c25aa7692184d00b90b1",
"lib/src/qr_code_scanner_web.dart": "50b70d762e80fedd228974e786e8f38a",
"lib/src/qr_code_scanner_web_impl.dart": "a0f12d21cc75aefe84f6fbf9c1e0307e",
"lib/src/qr_code_scanner_web_impl_no_web.dart": "11e3ab6339d41ded6e650c96120e7560",
"main.dart.js": "6161190dc35f953037fb5c0e7db4f0e6",
"manifest.json": "a281fd45bea620b437523746b29b93d2",
"pubspec.lock": "6c06cc012f6524824b77f7286b6e256e",
"pubspec.yaml": "b36c6ef43dcaa5a79fc412a8368306cf",
"version.json": "cbca785ad23c1984a075073af0a61003"
//Removed for brevity
};

// The application shell files that are downloaded before a service worker can
// start.
const CORE = [
  "/",
"main.dart.js",
"index.html",
"assets/NOTICES",
"assets/AssetManifest.json",
"assets/FontManifest.json"];
// During install, the TEMP cache is populated with the application shell files.
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
  return event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(TEMP).then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(
        CORE.map((value) => new Request(value, {'cache': 'reload'})));
    })
  );
});

// During activate, the cache is populated with the temp files downloaded in
// install. If this service worker is upgrading from one with a saved
// MANIFEST, then use this to retain unchanged resource files.
self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {
  return event.waitUntil(async function() {
    try {
      var contentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      var tempCache = await caches.open(TEMP);
      var manifestCache = await caches.open(MANIFEST);
      var manifest = await manifestCache.match('manifest');
      // When there is no prior manifest, clear the entire cache.
      if (!manifest) {
        await caches.delete(CACHE_NAME);
        contentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        for (var request of await tempCache.keys()) {
          var response = await tempCache.match(request);
          await contentCache.put(request, response);
        }
        await caches.delete(TEMP);
        // Save the manifest to make future upgrades efficient.
        await manifestCache.put('manifest', new Response(JSON.stringify(RESOURCES)));
        return;
      }
      var oldManifest = await manifest.json();
      var origin = self.location.origin;
      for (var request of await contentCache.keys()) {
        var key = request.url.substring(origin.length + 1);
        if (key == "") {
          key = "/";
        }
        // If a resource from the old manifest is not in the new cache, or if
        // the MD5 sum has changed, delete it. Otherwise the resource is left
        // in the cache and can be reused by the new service worker.
        if (!RESOURCES[key] || RESOURCES[key] != oldManifest[key]) {
          await contentCache.delete(request);
        }
      }
      // Populate the cache with the app shell TEMP files, potentially overwriting
      // cache files preserved above.
      for (var request of await tempCache.keys()) {
        var response = await tempCache.match(request);
        await contentCache.put(request, response);
      }
      await caches.delete(TEMP);
      // Save the manifest to make future upgrades efficient.
      await manifestCache.put('manifest', new Response(JSON.stringify(RESOURCES)));
      return;
    } catch (err) {
      // On an unhandled exception the state of the cache cannot be guaranteed.
      console.error('Failed to upgrade service worker: ' + err);
      await caches.delete(CACHE_NAME);
      await caches.delete(TEMP);
      await caches.delete(MANIFEST);
    }
  }());
});

// The fetch handler redirects requests for RESOURCE files to the service
// worker cache.
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
    return;
  }
  var origin = self.location.origin;
  var key = event.request.url.substring(origin.length + 1);
  // Redirect URLs to the index.html
  if (key.indexOf('?v=') != -1) {
    key = key.split('?v=')[0];
  }
  if (event.request.url == origin || event.request.url.startsWith(origin + '/#') || key == '') {
    key = '/';
  }
  // If the URL is not the RESOURCE list then return to signal that the
  // browser should take over.
  if (!RESOURCES[key]) {
    return;
  }
  // If the URL is the index.html, perform an online-first request.
  if (key == '/') {
    return onlineFirst(event);
  }
  event.respondWith(caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
    .then((cache) =>  {
      return cache.match(event.request).then((response) => {
        // Either respond with the cached resource, or perform a fetch and
        // lazily populate the cache.
        return response || fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      })
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // SkipWaiting can be used to immediately activate a waiting service worker.
  // This will also require a page refresh triggered by the main worker.
  if (event.data === 'skipWaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
    return;
  }
  if (event.data === 'downloadOffline') {
    downloadOffline();
    return;
  }
});

// Download offline will check the RESOURCES for all files not in the cache
// and populate them.
async function downloadOffline() {
  var resources = [];
  var contentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
  var currentContent = {};
  for (var request of await contentCache.keys()) {
    var key = request.url.substring(origin.length + 1);
    if (key == "") {
      key = "/";
    }
    currentContent[key] = true;
  }
  for (var resourceKey of Object.keys(RESOURCES)) {
    if (!currentContent[resourceKey]) {
      resources.push(resourceKey);
    }
  }
  return contentCache.addAll(resources);
}

// Attempt to download the resource online before falling back to
// the offline cache.
function onlineFirst(event) {
  return event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
      return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        return cache.match(event.request).then((response) => {
          if (response != null) {
            return response;
          }
          throw error;
        });
      });
    })
  );
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed`

I'm curious whether this error has something to do with CORS or not.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your domain address?

Comment: @reza It's hosted on a subdomain of the working domain, so it's like https://pwa.mydomain.com

Comment: When the files contain in `resources` and `CORE.map` lists returned 404 or other code, you'll get this exception. So make sure that all files return 200. Then it can execute well.